# How to clear the JMS queue in Jboss

Tags: jboss, jms, message-queue

I have a JMS queue in Jboss, and the queue has a messageselector like "UseId = myname".
myname is the Id for different users.
How can I clear the message in queue while the UseId is equal 0001 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
String name = "0001"; // or whatever

Session sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageConsumer mc = sess.createConsumer(queue, "UseId=" + name);

while (mc.receive(100L) != null)
    ;

sess.close();
```